# WSO2 MI and RabbitMQ: message format

Tags: rabbitmq, wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-micro-integrator

I am trying to work with RabbitMQ in WSO2 MI

I am using [RabbitMQ Message Store](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/synapse-properties/message-stores/rabbitmq-msg-store-properties/) to Produce messages:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<messageStore class="org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.rabbitmq.RabbitMQStore" name="RabbitMQMessageStore" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.ssl.keystore.password">wso2carbon</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.rabbitmq.host.name">rabbitmqserver.org</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.producer.guaranteed.delivery.enable">false</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.rabbitmq.route.key">test_key</parameter>
    <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.ssl.truststore.type"/>
    <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.ssl.enabled">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.rabbitmq.exchange.name">test_exchange</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.rabbitmq.queue.name">test_queue</parameter>
    <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.ssl.keystore.type">JKS</parameter>
    <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.ssl.version">SSL</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.rabbitmq.host.port">5672</parameter>
    <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.ssl.keystore.location">repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.rabbitmq.username">user</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.rabbitmq.virtual.host"/>
    <parameter name="store.rabbitmq.password">pass</parameter>
    <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.ssl.truststore.location">repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks</parameter>
    <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.ssl.truststore.password">wso2carbon</parameter>
</messageStore>
```

I have created REST API and in Sequence tried to produce messages in this way :

```
<sequence name="publishMessageSeq" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
    <property name="contentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
    <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
    <property name="rabbitmq.message.content.type" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
    <log level="full"/>
    <store messageStore="RabbitMQMessageStore"/>
</sequence>
```

I am sending JSON "{"publishId":"7ee7147d-a17b-44a0-b503-860f7b0139c9"}"

For consuming I am using [RabbitMQ Inbound Endpoint](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/synapse-properties/inbound-endpoints/event-based-inbound-endpoints/rabbitmq-inbound-endpoint-properties/)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inboundEndpoint name="RabbitmqInboundEndpoint" onError="RabbitMQConsumerFailedSeq" protocol="rabbitmq" sequence="RabbitMQConsumerSeq" suspend="false" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="sequential">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="coordination">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.factory">AMQPConnectionFactory</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.host.name">rabbitmqserver.org</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.port">5671</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.user.name">admin</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.password">admin</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.queue.name">test_queue_1</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.exchange.name">test_exchange_1</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.queue.durable">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.queue.exclusive">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.queue.auto.delete">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.queue.auto.ack">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.queue.routing.key">test_key</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.exchange.durable">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.exchange.auto.delete">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.ssl.enabled">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.ssl.keystore.location">$SYSTEM:KEYSTORE_PATH</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.ssl.keystore.type">JKS</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.ssl.keystore.password">$SYSTEM:KEYSTORE_PASSWORD</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.ssl.truststore.location">$SYSTEM:TRUSTSTORE_PATH</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.ssl.truststore.password">$SYSTEM:TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.ssl.version">SSL</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.message.content.type">application/json</parameter>
    </parameters>
</inboundEndpoint>
```

And this is the message I am getting:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <text
            xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">\uFFFD\uFFFD\u0000\u0005sr\u0000=org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.commons.StorableMessage\uFFFD@\uFFFDA\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\u0019\u0002\u0000\u0003I\u0000\bpriorityL\u0000\faxis2messaget\u0000&lt;Lorg/apache/synapse/message/store/impl/commons/Axis2Message;L\u0000\u000EsynapseMessaget\u0000>Lorg/apache/synapse/message/store/impl/commons/SynapseMessage;xp\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\u0019sr\u0000:org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.commons.Axis2Message8\u0010\uFFFDm\u0018\uFFFD~\u0002\u0000\u0014I\u0000\u0004FLOWZ\u0000\nisDoingGETZ\u0000\u000BisDoingMTOMZ\u0000\nisDoingPOXZ\u0000\nisDoingSWAL\u0000\u0006actiont\u0000\u0012Ljava/lang/String;L\u0000\u000EfaultToAddressq\u0000~\u0000\u0005L\u0000\u000BfromAddressq\u0000~\u0000\u0005[\u0000\njsonStreamt\u0000\u0002[BL\u0000\tmessageIDq\u0000~\u0000\u0005L\u0000\u000FoperationActionq\u0000~\u0000\u0005L\u0000\roperationNamet\u0000\u001BLjavax/xml/namespace/QName;L\u0000\npropertiest\u0000\u0013Ljava/util/HashMap;L\u0000\u0012relatesToMessageIdq\u0000~\u0000\u0005L\u0000\u000EreplyToAddressq\u0000~\u0000\u0005L\u0000\u0007serviceq\u0000~\u0000\u0005L\u0000\fsoapEnvelopeq\u0000~\u0000\u0005L\u0000\ttoAddressq\u0000~\u0000\u0005L\u0000\u000FtransportInNameq\u0000~\u0000\u0005L\u0000\u0010transportOutNameq\u0000~\u0000\u0005xp\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000pppur\u0000\u0002[B\uFFFD\uFFFD\u0017\uFFFD\u0006\bT\uFFFD\u0002\u0000\u0000xp\u0000\u0000\u00004{\"publishId\":\"7ee7147d-a17b-44a0-b503-860f7b0139c9\"}t\u00003urn:uuid:E2CF89B361CA458D882690439423903-1691448263t\u0000\u000Burn:mediatesr\u0000\u0019javax.xml.namespace.QName\uFFFDm\uFFFD-\uFFFD;\uFFFDl\u0002\u0000\u0003L\u0000\tlocalPartq\u0000~\u0000\u0005L\u0000\fnamespaceURIq\u0000~\u0000\u0005L\u0000\u0006prefixq\u0000~\u0000\u0005xpt\u0000\u0007mediatet\u0000\u0000q\u0000~\u0000\u0011sr\u0000\u0011java.util.HashMap\u0005\u0007\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\u0016`\uFFFD\u0003\u0000\u0002F\u0000\nloadFactorI\u0000\tthresholdxp?@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\fw\b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0010\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0007t\u0000\u0010ContainerManagedt\u0000\u0004truet\u0000\bWORK_DIRt\u0000!C:\\DEV\\WSO2MI~1.0\\bin\\..\\tmp\\workt\u00002local_org.wso2.ws.dataservice.db_service_extensiont\u0000\u0004.dbst\u0000\u001Blocal_current.server.statust\u0000\u0007RUNNINGt\u0000-local_org.wso2.ws.dataservice.db_service_repot\u0000C/C:/DEV/WSO2MI~1.0/bin/../repository/deployment/server/dataservicest\u0000\u0016ABSTRACT_MC_PROPERTIESsq\u0000~\u0000\u0012?@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0018w\b\u0000\u0000\u0000 \u0000\u0000\u0000\u0014t\u0000&lt;org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonInputStream.IsJsonObjectsr\u0000\u0011java.lang.Boolean\uFFFD r\uFFFD\u055C\uFFFD\uFFFD\u0002\u0000\u0001Z\u0000\u0005valuexp\u0001t\u0000\u000BREMOTE_HOSTt\u0000\u000F0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1t\u0000\u000BContentTypet\u0000\u0010application/jsont\u0000\u000BREMOTE_ADDRt\u0000\u000F0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1t\u0000\u0012HTTP_METHOD_OBJECTt\u0000\u0004POSTt\u0000\u001EdisableAddressingForInMessagest\u0000\u0005falset\u0000!synapse.internal.rest.contentTypet\u0000\u0010application/jsont\u0000\u000ESERVICE_PREFIXt\u0000\u001Dhttps://0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8253/t\u0000\u0014ClientApiNonBlockingsq\u0000~\u0000!\u0000t\u0000\u000BmessageTypeq\u0000~\u0000&amp;t\u0000\u0017message.builder.invokedq\u0000~\u0000\"t\u0000\u000ETransportInURLt\u0000 /rest/rabbitmq/check/publish-msgt\u0000\u001FdisableAddressingForOutMessagesq\u0000~\u0000\"t\u0000\u000Ecorrelation_idt\u0000I21d9e94b-5d13-4341-8c63-06bb4191c7b1_aeb91a51-797d-4c64-9d92-2bf36e4d54a1t\u0000\u0012synapse.isresponseq\u0000~\u00002t\u0000\u0010REST_URL_POSTFIXt\u0000\f/publish-msgt\u0000\u0015IsAddressingProcessedq\u0000~\u00002t\u0000\u000BcontentTypet\u0000\u0010application/jsont\u0000\u000BHTTP_METHODq\u0000~\u0000*t\u0000\u0016CHARACTER_SET_ENCODINGt\u0000\u0005UTF-8xt\u0000\u0011TRANSPORT_HEADERSsr\u0000\u0011java.util.TreeMap\f\uFFFD\uFFFD>-%j\uFFFD\u0003\u0000\u0001L\u0000\ncomparatort\u0000\u0016Ljava/util/Comparator;xppw\u0004\u0000\u0000\u0000\nt\u0000\u0006Acceptt\u0000\u000B*__SLASH__*t\u0000\u0018Accept__HYPHEN__Encodingt\u00001gzip__COMMA____SPACE__deflate__COMMA____SPACE__brt\u0000\nConnectiont\u0000\u0013keep__HYPHEN__alivet\u0000\u0017Content__HYPHEN__Lengtht\u0000\u000252t\u0000\u0015Content__HYPHEN__Typet\u0000\u0018application__SLASH__jsont\u0000\u0004Hostt\u0000\u0016localhost__COLON__8253t\u0000\u0016Postman__HYPHEN__Tokent\u0000H53b9a51a__HYPHEN__a258__HYPHEN__4383__HYPHEN__aca6__HYPHEN__0ce79784215ft\u0000\u0013User__HYPHEN__Agentt\u0000\u001DPostmanRuntime__SLASH__7.29.0t\u0000\nactivityidt\u0000H21d9e94b__HYPHEN__5d13__HYPHEN__4341__HYPHEN__8c63__HYPHEN__06bb4191c7b1t\u0000\u001Drabbitmq.message.content.typet\u0000\u0018application__SLASH__jsonxxppt\u0000\u0010__SynapseServicet\u0000\uFFFD&lt;?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>&lt;soapenv:Envelope
            xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">&lt;soapenv:Body>&lt;**jsonObject>&lt;publishId>7ee7147d-a17b-44a0-b503-860f7b0139c9&lt;/publishId>&lt;/jsonObject>**&lt;/soapenv:Body>&lt;/soapenv:Envelope>q\u0000~\u00006t\u0000\u0005httpst\u0000\u0005httpssr\u0000&lt;org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.commons.SynapseMessage\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD\u0018\uFFFD\u0145\uFFFD\u0002\u0000\u0007Z\u0000\rfaultResponseI\u0000\u0017messageFlowTracingStateZ\u0000\bresponseI\u0000\ftracingStateL\u0000\flocalEntriest\u0000\u0015Ljava/util/ArrayList;L\u0000\npropertiesq\u0000~\u0000\bL\u0000\u000FpropertyObjectsq\u0000~\u0000\bxp\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0002\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0002sr\u0000\u0013java.util.ArrayListx\uFFFD\uFFFD\u001D\uFFFD\uFFFDa\uFFFD\u0003\u0000\u0001I\u0000\u0004sizexp\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000w\u0004\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000xsq\u0000~\u0000\u0012?@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0018w\b\u0000\u0000\u0000 \u0000\u0000\u0000\u0011t\u00003_SYNAPSE_INTERNAL_REST_Access-Control-Allow-Methodst\u0000\u0004POSTt\u00003_SYNAPSE_INTERNAL_REST_Access-Control-Allow-Headersq\u0000~\u0000\u0011t\u0000\u000BREST_METHODq\u0000~\u0000*t\u0000\u0016REST_FULL_REQUEST_PATHq\u0000~\u00006t\u0000\u0010rest.url.patternt\u0000\f/publish-msgt\u0000\u0011TRANSPORT_IN_NAMEq\u0000~\u0000]t\u0000\u0013aggregateCorelationt\u0000-urn:uuid:21d9e94b-5d13-4341-8c63-06bb4191c7b1t\u0000\u0010REST_API_CONTEXTt\u0000\u0014/rest/rabbitmq/checkt\u0000\u0018SYNAPSE_REST_API_VERSIONq\u0000~\u0000\u0011t\u0000\u0013service.logger.namet\u0000\u0010RabbitMQCheckAPIt\u0000\bOUT_ONLYt\u0000\u0004trueq\u0000~\u00008t\u0000$21d9e94b-5d13-4341-8c63-06bb4191c7b1t\u0000\rARTIFACT_NAMEt\u0000\u0013apiRabbitMQCheckAPIt\u0000!SYNAPSE_REST_API_VERSION_STRATEGYq\u0000~\u0000\u0011t\u0000\u0012tenant.info.domaint\u0000\fcarbon.supert\u0000\u0015REST_SUB_REQUEST_PATHt\u0000\f/publish-msgt\u0000\u000FREST_URL_PREFIXt\u0000\u0016https://localhost:8253xsq\u0000~\u0000\u0012?@\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000w\b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0010\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000x
        </text>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So I can see my JSON object in this mess ""><soapenv:Body><**jsonObject><publishId>7ee7147d-a17b-44a0-b503-860f7b0139c9</publishId></jsonObject>**</soapenv:Body>" but I want receive my json only, not this weird SOAP envelope. Could you please help me to configure it correctly? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using Message Stores here. If you are using a Message Store to store the message you should be using a Message Processor to consume the message. Message stores are tightly coupled with Message Processors, and serializes the message when storing in the queue. If you use a Message processor it knows how to deserialize the content.

Hence use the `Send` or `Call` mediator to store the message and then use an Inbound Endpoint to consume the message.

```xml
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="AMQPProducerSample" transports="http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
<target>
 <inSequence>
    <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
    <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
     <send>
      <endpoint>
       <address uri="rabbitmq:/AMQPProducerSample?rabbitmq.server.host.name=localhost&amp;rabbitmq.server.port=5672&amp;rabbitmq.queue.name=queue&amp;rabbitmq.queue.route.key=route&amp;rabbitmq.exchange.name=exchange"/>
      </endpoint>
    </send>
 </inSequence>
 <outSequence>
        <send/>
 </outSequence>
</target>
<description/>
</proxy>
```

Full example [here](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.0.0/micro-integrator/use-cases/examples/jms_examples/rabbitmq-examples/#micro-integrator-as-a-rabbitmq-message-producer).